# VBA - Error 400 when I want to delete a column filtered and masked

Tags: vba, excel

I have a problem. In my VBA, I copy my workbook in an other workbook, and after that, all columns masked are deleted. It work perfectely, except when I filter the table, the VBA show me `Error 400` when it tried to delete a masked column.

The bug is here : `ActiveSheet.Columns(C).Delete`

Here's my code :

```
Sub Test(targetWorkbookName As String)
S1 = Sheets("PARAM").Range("G35").Value
Dim F As Integer, C As Integer, derniereligne
Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook
On Error Resume Next
Set targetWorkbook = Workbooks(targetWorkbookName)
On Error GoTo 0
If (targetWorkbook Is Nothing) Then _
    Set targetWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(targetWorkbookName)
```

My loop to delete masked columns (And where the error is):

```
    For F = 1 To Sheets.Count
    ActiveSheet.Select
    For C = 15 To 2 Step -1
        ActiveSheet.Columns(C).Select
        Selection.End(xlDown).Select
        derniereligne = ActiveCell.Row
        If ActiveSheet.Columns(C).Hidden = True Then
            ActiveSheet.Columns(C).Delete
        End If
    Next C
Next F
```

The rest of the first sub

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Sheets("PARAM").Delete
 ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Button 2")).Select
            Selection.Delete
 ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Button 9")).Select
            Selection.Delete

        Dim ret As Integer
        ret = MsgBox("Voulez-vous verouiller la feuille ?", vbYesNo)
        If ret = vbYes Then
            Sheets("A").Protect Password:=S1
        End If

targetWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=targetWorkbookName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
'targetWorkbook.Close savechanges:=True

 End Sub
```

The first sub which save as my excel :

```
Sub SaveXL()

Dim Nom2 As String
Dim Jour2 As String
Dim FPath2 As String
Jour2 = Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd - h\hmm")
Nom2 = Jour2 & " Pricelist"
FPath2 = Sheets("PARAM").Range("B33").Value
'On Error GoTo fin4
fichier = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(FPath2 & Nom2, "Fichiers Excel (*.xls), *.xls")
If fichier <> "Faux" Then
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs fichier
    Test GetAName(fichier)
Else
    MsgBox "Le fichier n'a pas été enregistré"
End If
Exit Sub
'fin4:         MsgBox "La création de l'excel a échoué"
 End Sub
```

Could you help me ? Thanks.

Comment: So you only get this error when there is a filter on a column?

Comment: What's the purpose of the `For F = 1 to Sheets.Count` loop?  It doesn't change the sheet, and you're always working on ActiveSheet.  So if you have 5 sheets, you're going to have 5 turns at deleting columns 15 to 2?

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is the filter just remove any filters from the sheet first using `ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False`. Also as per Daves comment, your loop is doing nothing, better off using something like the following.

```
Dim wks As Worksheet
For Each wks In Me.Worksheets
    wks.Activate
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    For C = 15 To 2 Step -1
        ActiveSheet.Columns(C).Select
        Selection.End(xlDown).Select
        derniereligne = ActiveCell.Row
        If ActiveSheet.Columns(C).Hidden = True Then
            ActiveSheet.Columns(C).Delete
        End If
    Next C
Next wks
```

Alternatively to keep your `F = 1` select each sheet by its index number, not `ActiveSheet`, as that's doing nothing.

```
For F = 1 To Sheets.Count
    Sheets(F).Select
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    For C = 15 To 2 Step -1
    ActiveSheet.Columns(C).Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    derniereligne = ActiveCell.Row
        If ActiveSheet.Columns(C).Hidden = True Then
            ActiveSheet.Columns(C).Delete
        End If
    Next C
Next F
```

Comment: `ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False` doesn't work, again error 400, it change nothing :/
And I can't remove filters, because I want to duplicate the first workbook with filters.

Comment: Are you able to share a copy of the file?

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, I found a solution :

In fact, I noted, the macro can't delete a column masked and filtered, so I decided to unmask columns masked and after that, delete them.

```
If ActiveSheet.Columns(C).Hidden = True Then
            ActiveSheet.Columns(C).Hidden = False
            ActiveSheet.Columns(C).Delete
End If
```

I didn't find a better solution...